# Reprojecting a UTM map to equidistant cylindrical projection

Tags: grass-gis

I just recently started to work with GRASS GIS (version 6.4.4)... as I imported a UTM map of Svalbard, I would like to change its projection to equidistant cylindrical. After looking up the EPSG code for equidistant cylindrical I tried changing the projection information with g.prop epsg=1029 (or 9823), but all I got was an error message:

```
ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 1029 not found in EPSG support files.
```

Is this a valid EPSG coordinate system?

How can I apply this projection to my map?

Do I have to modify the EPSG support files?

---

This does not work:

```
yadgar@HEXACORE:~$ grass -c EPSG:54002 /home/yadgar/grassdata/svalbard/svalbard/EquiCyl/PERMANENT
Creating new GRASS GIS location/mapset...
FEHLER: ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 54002 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a valid
EPSG coordinate system?
```

Answer (score 1):

First, please upgrade your GRASS. You are working with a 10 year old version!

Second "equidistant cylindrical" is a projection method, not a specific coordinate reference system. The EPSG code 1029 seems to be a simple cartesian reference system - not what you want. The World Equidistant Cylindrical CRS is referred to as 54002:  [see epsg.io website](http://epsg.io/54002)

Next, to reproject in GRASS you must first create a new location defined by the target reference system. Then, start GRASS in that new location, and run r.proj from there. So, you can create a new LOCATION/MAPSET as follows (using a **newer version** of GRASS):

```
# Before starting GRASS, from the command line

grass -c EPSG:54002 <path/to/your/GRASSDB/EquiCyl/PERMANENT>
```

Then, once GRASS starts in the new location, run:

```
r.proj location=<Previous_UTM_location> mapset=<Previous_UTM_mapset> input=<Previous_map> output=<New_reprojected_map>
```

Comment: This does not work:

yadgar@HEXACORE:~$ grass -c EPSG:54002 /home/yadgar/grassdata/svalbard/svalbard/EquiCyl/PERMANENT Creating new GRASS GIS location/mapset... FEHLER: ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 54002 not found in EPSG support files. Is this a valid EPSG coordinate system?

Comment: @Yadgar, No, it is an ESRI (not EPSG) code. Its true scale latitude is 60 degrees. The world equidistant cylindrical EPSG code is 4087 for the wgs84 datum, or 4088 for a spherical datum. Are you sure that you are looking for an equidistant cylindrical (and not a pseudo Plate Carrée) projection?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, and thanks gabriel-de-luca for correcting me.